# When reading from files, do you check the EOF condition before or after reading

Tags: file, input, file-io, filereader, pseudocode

Using pseudocode...

```
aFile = open("file.txt")
//x = aFile.readLine()  <- reading before checking end of file condition
while !aFile.endOfFile()
    //x = aFile.readLine() <- only read if you have not already read 
                                          from the file before the loop
    print(x)
    //x = aFile.readLine()  <- if reading before checking end of file, 
                            you will read again after printing the previous x value
end while
aFile.close()
```

My question is, would you need to read from the file before you can check the endOfFile condition holds false or would you check the condition before reading from the file?

Answer (score 0):

To get information about end of file You first have to access this file(stream). Then it depends on language/function You are using to check this condition. But for example in C You can do it in this way:

```
FILE * pFile;
int c;
int n = 0;
pFile=fopen ("myfile.txt","r");

do {
  //First get character
  c = fgetc (pFile);
  //Then check for EOF(end of line)
} while (c != EOF);

fclose (pFile);
```